# How to get specific key from Gmail API json with Python?

Tags: python, json, gmail-api

In the Python Gmail API documentation, the get function gives a json output and I'm able to access the "snippet" data.  I'd like to access the "value" information of the "headers" key.  I feel like this should be simply getting multi-level JSON data, but it's escaping me.  Can someone help me out please?

http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#get

```
{ # An email message.
      **"headers": [ # List of headers on this message part. For the top-level message part, representing the entire message payload, it will contain the standard RFC 2822 email headers such as To, From, and Subject.**
        {
          "name": "A String", # The name of the header before the : separator. For example, To.
          **"value": "A String", # The value of the header after the : separator. For example, someuser@example.com.**
        },
      ],
    "snippet": "A String", # A short part of the message text.
    "raw": "A String", # The entire email message in an RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string. Returned in messages.get and drafts.get responses when the format=RAW parameter is supplied.
    "sizeEstimate": 42, # Estimated size in bytes of the message.
    "threadId": "A String", # The ID of the thread the message belongs to. To add a message or draft to a thread, the following criteria must be met:
        # - The requested threadId must be specified on the Message or Draft.Message you supply with your request.
        # - The References and In-Reply-To headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard.
        # - The Subject headers must match.
    "labelIds": [ # List of IDs of labels applied to this message.
      "A String",
    ],
    "id": "A String", # The immutable ID of the message.
  }
```

```py
        for message in messages:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
            print(msg['snippet']) # This works
            print(msg['value']) # This doesn't and I tried ['headers']['value'] also.
            print("\n")
            time.sleep(1)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Notebook/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/Gmail.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Notebook/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/Gmail.py", line 58, in main
    print("New Message: " + msg['value'])
KeyError: 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Key `"value"` exists in the header. You can access it using `msg["headers"][0]["value"]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it says KeyError: "headers".  I tried without the [0] index too and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did a pretty print on the JSON file and I think the Python Gmail API is wrong.  The headers and respective data I was actually looking for was in the 'payload' section. Is this an efficient way to get the data or am I doing it wrong?

```py
         for message in messages:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
            message_from = msg['payload']['headers'][4]
            print("You have a new message from: " + message_from['value'])
            print(msg['snippet'])
            print("\n")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: To get a feeling about the data structure, use the `Try this API` https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get . You will see that the response JSON will be somerthing like `"payload": {
  "partId": "",
  "mimeType": "text/plain",
  "filename": "",
  "headers": [
   {...` So, as you correctly assumed "headers" are a part of "payload".

Comment: @ziganotschka awesome, thanks.  So I've tested my code and different e-mails have different 'headers' so my reference to the [4] index doesn't come up with the same thing each time.  Is there a way to do more than key value pairs?

Comment: You might want to search in your headers the one with the `"name": "From"`